# Duplicating a string variable in awk

Tags: awk

I would like to precede each line with a number saying how many slashes the line has got.

```
awk '{ l=$0; gsub("[^/]","",l); print length(l),l }'
```

This doesn't work bacause `l=$0` seems to assign by reference.
How do I `dup` the string?

Is there a better way to do this with standard UNIX tools?
I essentially want to sort a list of filepaths by depth (slash count).

Comment: I actually wanted to use this with `git ls-files`, but I'm solving my problem differently in the end. At least I learned something about `awk`.

Comment: It doesn't assign by reference. It works exactly as expected. You are making the susbtitution on `l`, then printing `l`. Why would you expect it to be unchanged? Presumably, you meant to do `awk '{l=$0; gsub("[^/]","",l); print length(l),$0}` which does what you want.

Comment: @terdon Stupid me. Thanks. Yeah, I did mean `awk '{l=$0; gsub("[^/]","",l); print length(l),$0}` but wrote `awk '{l=$0; gsub("[^/]","",l); print length(l),l}`. I hate these typos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `awk` always do assignment by value, not by reference.

The *RHS* of variable assignment is an [expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_02), and an expression in `awk` always return a value. To duplicate a variable, just assigning its value to new variable, you can operate on new variable without *affecting* the original variable.

In:

```
$ echo 1 | awk '{l=$0; sub("1","2",l); print l, $0}'
2 1
```

only value of `l` was modified, `$0` value wasn't changed.

---

With your requirement in the question, simply do:

```
awk -F '/' '{print NF-1, $0}' <file
```

You don't need to do any parsing work, let `awk` do it all for you before you enter the script body. You only need to extract the information.

Answer (score 6):

Per the manual:

```
gsub(regexp, replacement [, target])
```

(if target is omitted, default to `$0`). `gsub()` returns the number of substitutions made so in your case you want to replace slashes to get the count:

```
awk '{l=$0; print gsub("/", ""), l}'
```

but as Etan Reisner notices, the assignment isn't even needed in this case:

```
awk '{print gsub("/", "/"), $0}'
```

Comment: Replace slashes with slashes and you don't need `l` at all. Since you don't modify the line in the first place. Just `{print gsub(/\//, "/"), $0}'.

Comment: Don't use regex substitution for this task, you can face a performance issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use `split` instead:

```
   split(s, a[, fs ])
             Split the string s into array elements a[1], a[2], ..., a[n],
             and return n.  All elements of the  array  shall  be  deleted
             before  the  split is performed. The separation shall be done
             with the ERE fs or with the field separator FS if fs  is  not
             given. [. . .]
```

So, given this input file:

```
$ cat file
no slashes
one / slash
two / and /
consecutive 3 ///
none
one /
```

You could do:

```
$ awk '{ n=split($0,a,"/"); print n-1,$0}' file
0 no slashes
1 one / slash
2 two / and /
3 consecutive 3 ///
0 none
1 one /
```

Comment: The `split` is not needed, let `awk` do it all for you using `Field Separator`. See [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245328/38906).

Comment: Yeah, this is almost certainly the right solution... unless you need `FS` for something else at the same time.